# Input mask Jquery

Tags: jquery, input, input-mask

I am trying to get input mask in JQ plugin, I want this format

```
part1/part2
```

part 1 can be any number of digits.

part 2 should be fixed 4 digits.

in between the 2 parts slash "/"

```
$(".mask").inputmask('[9]{1,4}/9999');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
$(".mask").mask('##/0000', {reverse: true});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Regex masks:

```
$(".mask").mask({regex: "\\d+\\/\\d{4}"});
```

Comment: both parts not wrking